# $200 reward! Sent tron to a contract I created accidentally

Tags: go-ethereum

Just curious. I sent a little bit of tron to a contract that I created. I can access the wallet I used to create said contract - but in order to access the tron I sent to the contract I'd need to address it through metamask, or something? I only have the actual wallet orginally used to create the contract.

[This](https://etherscan.io/address/0xcb26e4b2ef5b1bbfe5e5d9f636c6b99795825b2d) is the contract

and [this](https://etherscan.io/address/0x24f0b0912c97b46c9c4778f4b960b4ed2b022c0f) is the wallet that was used to create it

I'll give anyone $200in TRX/ETH if they can figure this out.

Just to note as well - I do not have the original source code saved when I created this contract using http://remix.ethereum.org/ - IS there a way to still salvage the tron, and withdraw it?

Answer (score 1):

> or something?

If your contract has no functions implemented to call the token contract's `transfer()` function (to transfer its tokenbalance back to you), there is no way for you to ever get your tokens back.

Answer (score 1):

If the contract you created has a function to call upon the Tron contract's  transfer function, then yes it is possible.

Otherwise unfortunately those tokens are lost in ETH-Limbo.

Comment: Is there... a simple way to understand how to "call" a contract?

Comment: Contracts can execute functions in other contracts if you programmed it to do that (when you wrote the Solidity). If you don't remember writing any code in your contract that would locate the Tron contract and call any of its functions, then those tokens are 100% lost, sorry.